# Why is List<Exception> list = new List<ApplicationException>(); not valid?

Tags: c#, generics

Why is this statement not valid?

```
List<Exception> list = new List<ApplicationException>();
```

As far as ApplicationException is a Exception descendant all operations, available with List are available with List.

So, what's the design reason to deny such a behavior?

Comment: Add the next line - `list.Add(new NotAnApplicationException());` - and ponder what your `List`, that was told it would contain `ApplicationException` objects, is going to do.

Comment: I never tried like this, but why do you need a list of exceptions?

Comment: Don't feed lions with giraffes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanks a lot. Never thought in such a way.